# EF adding User without User ID in Sql-Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to add Users to my database Using DB Set but I am collecting only information about the Username and the password how can I add without UserID?

This is my constructor:

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }

        public User(string username, string password)
        {
            this.Id =  1;
            this.Username = username;
            this.Password = password;
        }
```

And this is my Adding method:

```
                User user = new User(username, password);
                UserContext.Users.Add(user);
                UserContext.SaveChanges();
```

When I execute my code the database is still empty.

Comment: Can you share your entire user model please?

Comment: Yes, I edited the post

Answer (score 1):

Try annotate the property like below to use the Auto-Increment https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }

    public User(string username, string password)
    {
        this.Username = username;
        this.Password = password;
    }
}
```

or use fluent api like this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasKey(p => new { p.Id });

modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```